# I get google cloud error that I do not have a support role

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, permission-denied, access-denied

I get this error in Google cloud as I go to buy Google cloud support.

You're seeing this page because you don't have a support role. To access Role-Based Support, please contact your Support Account Administrator or Organization Administrator.

As a mention, I already has owner, editor and viewer permission in Google cloud and I checked google service page and allowed all IAM roles but yet I am getting this error. Please send me reply of how to solve this.

Any hint also very helpful for me.
Hope to hear from you soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support contracts are tied to the organization, not to the project. You'll need the role roles/cloudsupport.admin at the organization level to purchase support.
See info: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/role-based-support#support_account_administrator_role